# Strange behavior of custom allocator

Tags: c++

If I run the program, it will return SIGSEGV. If I dissasemble it and debug, I saw that it crash at begin of function `dCAllocator::free()`.

```
#include <cstdlib>

class dCAllocator
{
public:
    void * alloc(unsigned long size)
    {
        return malloc(size);
    }
    void free(void * p)
    {
        free(p);
    }
};
int main()
{
    dCAllocator dalloc;
    int * arr = (int*)dalloc.alloc(sizeof(int)*40);
    for (int i=0; i<40; ++i)
        arr[i] = i*2;
    for (int i=0; i<40; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "END" << endl;
    dalloc.free(arr);  // There is SIGSEGV
    cout << "OF DEALLOCATION" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're recursing into your own `free()` implementation. Use the global scope resolution operator `::free(p)` or choose a different member name than `free()` (`deallocate` springs to mind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `free()` member will call itself until it runs out of stack space. You probably meant to call `::free()`:

```
void dCAllocator::free(void* ptr) {
    ::free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I'd call std::free(ptr) instead ;)  Well, actually I'd use delete, but I presume the allocator in the question is academic since it's obviously not useful as-is.  And the type taken by alloc() should probably be std::size_t.